# Spring Boot and Spring MVC are actually frameworks or not?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I know that the Spring Framework is a Framework, but the emergence of Spring Boot and Spring MVC makes me confused whether it is a framework or just one of the modules that Spring Framework has?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Spring is the most popular application framework for develop java base web application and spring framework core feature can be use any java application.

Also many people refer to **Spring web MVC** as a framework.
There is nothing wrong with that.
In other words, the spring web MVC is a part of the spring framework that is designed to implement web part in our application.
[spring framework img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFA5O.png)
The Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is designed around a DispatcherServlet that dispatches requests to handlers, with configurable handler mappings, view resolution, locale and theme resolution as well as support for uploading files.

**Spring Boot** Framework is widely used to develop REST APIs
If analyzed in depth **Spring Boot is a project that is built on the top of the Spring Framework**. It provides an easier and faster way to set up, configure, and run both simple and web-based applications.
In short, Spring Boot is the combination of Spring Framework and Embedded Servers.
[spring boot img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYcO.png)

read more [Web MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

read more [Spring boot](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/index.htm#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20is%20an%20open,is%20developed%20by%20Pivotal%20Team.&text=Spring%20Boot%20contains%20a%20comprehensive,you%20can%20%E2%80%9Cjust%20run%E2%80%9D.)